# sql injection login form error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am working on tutorial about how to make an sql injection with old php code. I have this code that I am testing on it, but I have an error that said:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

This is the old code:

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password="root"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="graphic_db"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="login"; // Table name 
//if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){
//header("location:index.html");
  $con=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$db_name);



if(isset($_POST['login_submit'])){

    if($_POST['username'] != '' && $_POST['password']!=''){
        if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    { 
        session_start();
        //session_register('username'); 
    } 

        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='" . $_POST["username"] . "' and password = '". $_POST["password"]."'");
        while($row  = $result->fetch_assoc($result) ){
        if(is_array($row)) {
            $_SESSION["username"] = $row[$_POST["username"]];
            $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST["username"];

            header("Location:home.php");
            } 
            else {
            $message = "Invalid Username or Password!";

            }

        }
        }

        }

?>
```

Comment: Never directly put POST variables into a query. Take a look at mysqli_escape_string or use prepared statements.

Comment: Sir I am making a code that is vulnerable into SQL injections to teach it to my students so they will understand how sql injections can be done and then How they can correct it

Answer (score 3):

You have mixing  `Object oriented style` and  `Procedural style` in your code .Use only one style as

In **Object oriented style**

```
$result = $mysqli->query( "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='" . $_POST["username"] . "' and password = '". $_POST["password"]."'");
 while($row  = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
```

In **Procedural style**

```
 $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='" . $_POST["username"] . "' and password = '". $_POST["password"]."'");
 while($row  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ){
```

Read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Sir I am making a code that is vulnerable into SQL injections to teach it to my students so they will understand how sql injections can be done and then How they can correct it

Answer (score 0):

try this code
`$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

Answer (score 0):

```
    $host="localhost"; // Host name 
    $username="root"; // Mysql username 
    $password="root"; // Mysql password 
    $db_name="graphic_db"; // Database name 
    $tbl_name="login"; // Table name 
    session_start();
    $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);

    if(isset($_POST['login_submit'])){
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM login WHERE email=? AND  password=? ");
        $email = $_POST['username'];
        $password = md5($_POST['password']);
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $password);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($email, $password);
        $stmt->store_result();

        if($stmt->num_rows == 1)  //To check if the row exists
        {
            while($stmt->fetch()) //fetching the contents of the row
            {
                $_SESSION['Logged'] = 1;
                   $_SESSION['Email'] = $email;
                   header('Location: home.php');
                   exit();
            }

        }
        else 
        {
            echo "Wrong Username or Password!";
        }
        $stmt->close();
        $stmt->free_result();
    }
```

Use prepared query for your sql injection code. it is best practice for it.

Prepared statements are very useful against SQL injections, because parameter values, which are transmitted later using a different protocol, need not be correctly escaped. If the original statement template is not derived from external input, SQL injection cannot occur.

Comment: No I need a code that is vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: Sir I am making a code that is vulnerable into SQL injections to teach it to my students so they will understand how sql injections can be done and then How they can correct it